# Will a stock always correct itself on the ex-div date?

Tags: stocks, dividends, portfolio, ex-dividend-date

I have a position in a stock (oil company) which has already announced a ~7% dividend with the ex-div date set to 13 May and payment date to 7 June.

I am looking to double my position in this stock ***but only if*** there's a ~7% correction on the ex-div date, which seems to be the general rule.

The question is, will a stock always correct itself to minus the dividend amount on the ex-div date ?

thanks

Comment: Does your question assume that there will be no price fluctuations?

Comment: Yes, the stock is currently growing steadily into ex-div and yes I am assuming there won't be a major correction before ex-div. My plan is to double the position if the ex-div correction comes, then sell the entire position if it bounces up quickly. Otherwise hold.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct itself"? You mean bounce back to the price it was _before_ the dividend? The answer is assuredly no, not always.

Comment: Yes, the price will fall by approximately the amount of the dividend. Why do you think the stock price will "bounce up quickly" afterwards? I don't see why there must be a rebound.

Comment: @DStanley: After a stock goes ex-dividend, the share price typically drops by the amount of the dividend paid. The questions was, does that ALWAYS, 100% happen ? Or it could be, or it could be not ? :)

Comment: @Flux: I am assuming there would be a rebound (quick or slow) because its a strong company and generally energy will get stronger as more vaccination is pushed (this is a personal opinion of course).

Comment: Are you saying that you are expecting the increase in stock price (rebound) to be caused by the decline in stock price (caused by the dividend)?

Comment: Probably related: [Is it legal to “mine” dividends?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/98139/is-it-legal-to-mine-dividends)

Comment: Trying to rephase: I am expecting the stock to drop 7%*** on the ex-div and I am expecting to dip buy it and hold until it rebounds for whatever reason, then sell. ***(but i am not sure if that's always the case and that was the question)

Comment: Why would you only double your position _after_ the dividend? If you doubled it _before_, you'd get twice the dividend and be back in the same position (wealth wise)/

Comment: If you think the stock will drop by the amount of the dividend, it doesn’t matter whether you buy additional shares before or after the ex-div date. If you think it won’t drop by that much (or if you’re not sure), then you should **definitely** buy more shares *before* the date.

Comment: @DStanley , that's actually a very poor idea, as the net result is identical, and dividends have an immediate tax liability. Basically, you _volunteer_ to pay some extra taxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes a stock will *on average* drop by the amount of a dividend. The *actual* change can fluctuate during the day just based on normal market fluctuations. But things like market stop and limit orders will adjust automatically by the exchange by the *exact* amount of the dividend due to this effect.

The *reason* that a stock drops after a dividend is because *it has sent cash out the door*. If a company is worth $100 per share, and gives $10 per share to its shareholders, that company is now worth $10 less (because of the cash out the door). From a shareholder wealth standpoint it's a wash since it now has a $90 share and $10 cash.

What the stock does *from there* is not guaranteed. It can go back up, or go down for completely unrelated reasons, but there's no fundamental reason that the stock would go one way or the other after the dividend adjustment.

(there may be some *patterns* that can be observed before and after dividend announcement/ex-div that can be exploited *on average*, but they are not guaranteed and there's no fundamental reason for a single stock to behave any differently just because a dividend has been paid)

> I am looking to double my position in this stock but only if there's a ~7% correction on the ex-div date

From a wealth standpoint, it won't matter (other than rate and timing of taxes). Say the stock is at $100 today and has announced a 7% ($7) dividend, and you own 100 shares for a total value of $10,000. All else being equal, after the ex-div date the stock will drop to $93 and you'll be eligible for a $7 dividend. Your total wealth from this stock will still be $10,000 ($9,300 in stock and $700 in cash) less any taxes you'd owe on the dividend (but the capital gains you'd pay eventually on the stock would be lower as well). If you double *before* the ex-div, you'll still have $20,000 ($18,600 in stock and $1,400 in cash). If you double after, you'll *also* have $20,000 ($18,600 in stock, $700 in cash form the dividend and $700 "saved" from buying at $93 instead of $100).

Comment: Assuming all else equal, the one difference between buying before the ex-div date and after is taxation if the dividend is received in a non sheltered account.

Comment: True, there can be a difference in tax treatment, but that's not germane to the question (IMHO)

Comment: I'm not the one who stated that they're the same: **From a shareholder wealth standpoint it's a wash.** It would only be a wash if there is no taxation.

Comment: Share price drops overnight  by the exact  amount of the dividend on the ex-div date not some 'average' amount.  The close to close one day change before and including the ex-div date will vary due to subsequent trading resumes on the ex-div date.

Answer (score 3):

Yes a stock will always drop by the amount of a dividend.

The *reason* that a stock drops after a dividend is because just before the ex-div date, that stock was worth its actual value plus the guaranteed dividend. If the objective value of a share is $90, and that share also provides $10 per share to its shareholders tomorrow, that company share will be traded at a value of $100. From a shareholder wealth standpoint it's a wash since after the ex-dividend date they now have a $90 share and $10 cash.

What the stock does from there is not guaranteed. It can go back up, or go down for completely unrelated reasons, but there's no fundamental reason that the stock would go one way or the other after the dividend adjustment.

The question about whether you buy a stock the day before the ex-dividend date or the day after will not make much of a difference. Before the ex-dividend date, you are basically paying $10 extra in order to compensate the previous owner for the $10 dividend they are going to miss out on tomorrow. But you are going to get those back when the dividend is paid. So you won't save any money by waiting for a day.

(Yes, this answer is partially based on the answer by D Stanley. It boils down to the exact same conclusions, but I find this perspective of looking at it a lot easier to understand)

Comment: Never said anything about buying before ex-div. I already have a position in this stock and looking to double it AFTER ex-div, in case the price drops by the amount of the dividend.

Comment: @lmlmlm I see. But that doesn't change much. I updated the answer.

Comment: "just before the ex-div date, that stock was worth its actual value plus the guaranteed dividend" This is a bit misleading. The "actual value" of the stock goes down because the value of the company that it represents goes down. It's not like $10 of value is "created" just by declaring a dividend (which is how this could be interpreted).

Comment: @DStanley Your perspective is just as misleading, because it implies that the market cap of a company and the net worth of a company are the same thing. Which is simply not true. The value of a company according to the accountants and according to the investors can be very different.

Answer (score -2):

You can check this by looking at history.

There are many stocks that issued a percentage dividend and then did NOT drop by that percentage on the ex-dividend date.

The reasons why are many and various, but that's not what you asked.

Comment: What data are you looking at? On of my stocks is traded ex-Div today and is at -2,70€ at the moment. However, on opening it was at -3,30€ which happens to be exactly the dividend.Historical data on closing price is not helpful for ex-dividend, you need the closing of the dividend and the opening of the ex-div

Comment: Let's just pick the first one I find...

BPMP, ex-div a few days ago. Closed 13.86 , dividend of 0.348 , opened at 13.60 

Dropped, but not by the same amount as the dividend. Anyone looking for a guarantee that a stock will drop by the same amount as the dividend is asking for something that just isn't guaranteed.

Comment: @Moschops a stock can change by more or less than the dividend just due to normal price fluctuations during the day (or changes in expected future performance). The point is that the stock should be expected _on average_ to drop by the dividend amount. Meaning if you took 100 independent dividend-paying stocks and look at their changes relative to their dividend, you should expect an _average_ change very close the the dividend amount.

Comment: @Moschops - You do not understand the ex-dividend process.  In the U.S. stock exchanges reduce share price by the exact amount of the dividend on the ex-dividend BEFORE shares resume trading on the ex-div date.  When trading resumes, share price may increase, decrease or remain the same.  By looking at the close to close change, you are conflating the ex-div process with price change due to subsequent trading.

Comment: cont. - If you want to see this clearly, find an ex-div for tomorrow and compare tomight's closing price with tomorrow's adjusted close BEFORE trading resumes.  You'll see that share price has dropped EXACTLY the amount of the dividend.  Furthermore, FINRA Rule 5330 requires that all open orders must be adjusted by the amount of the dividend in order to avoid premature order execution due to this share price reduction.

Comment: Wow, even open orders get adjusted ? I did not visualize this situation, very useful info guys thank you

Comment: @D Stanley ; I agree. I'd expect it to mostly do that. But it's not law. It's not guaranteed.

Comment: @Bob Baerker.  That's an open order. It's not the "price" of the stock.